# how to get mapbox-gl-js webgl/opengl to work on ubuntu chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, opengl-es, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

We are trying mapbox-gl page here: https://www.mapbox.com/blog/data-driven-styling/

We see [image]

This is the Chrome Version:

```
Google Chrome   50.0.2661.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Revision    0c319c380220abe3daf0277e40a2d0b22a7c4550-refs/branch-heads/2661@{#645}
OS  Linux 
Blink   537.36 (@0c319c380220abe3daf0277e40a2d0b22a7c4550)
JavaScript  V8 5.0.71.39
Flash   21.0.0.216
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36
Command Line    /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --window-depth=24 --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
Executable Path /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
```

This is the linux ubuntu version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

Is this a web-gl issue?  our code issue?  mapbox-gl-js library issue?

It works in Firefox :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that for Chrome on Ubuntu, hardware acceleration should be on.

See settings -> advanced in Chrome

[image]

Comment: That's not sufficient in all cases: I have an Nvidia GPU with the nouveau driver and was affected by [the GPU process failing to start](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660493)

Answer (score 0):

Your console has an error message that says:

```
Failed to initialize WebGL
```

This means that your browser + hardware combination does not support some of the features that are needed to run Mapbox GL JS.

You may be able to resolve this issue with an update to your browser or graphics card drivers.

Comment: Thanks but it works perfectly on the same machine/OS with Firefox, so it appears to mean that Chrome 50.0.2661.94 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Ubuntu 15.10 does not support WebGL but it some times works (I believe) it is a very strange one. Thanks for your answer, though :)